# Which is better? DataTable.Select() or Linq for filtering objects?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary

I'm storing a collection of objects of custom class type. I've given the type below.

```
public class AnonymousClient
{
   private string ipAddress, city, country, category;
   private Guid id;
}
```

I may have to get the objects filtered based on city, country, category etc. I'm able to think of two ways -

1. Storing it in a dictionary
   `Dictionary<Guid, AnonymousClient>`
   and using Linq to filter the
   objects.
2. Storing it in a `DataTable` with
   multiple columns for the members
   and using DataTable.Select() to
   filter the records.

I guess both of them loop internally. Which one is faster and elegant? Any insights?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422015/datatable-select-vs-linq-select

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not performing Linq To SQL though.

Comment: Have you looked at [i4o - Indexed LINQ](http://i4o.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: It is cool. But I can't convince others to work with a beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a DataTable would add quite a bit of overhead. It's easier to run a query once you set it up, because the code for it is already created, but it won't run as fast.

If you want to look up items using the `id` you can use a `Dictionary<Guid, AnonymousClient>`, if you only want to filter the data on the other fields you can just use a `List<AnonymousClient>`.

The most efficient would be to simply loop the collection yourself and pick out the items. LINQ is almost as efficient, but it adds a slight bit of overhead. On the other hand, the LINQ code gets very simple.

Example using the LINQ extension method `Where`:

```
var companies = clients.Where(c => c.category == "Company");
```

Comment: Can you think of any other data structure or methodology to create objects collection in a way where we can filter it without performance overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first approach. But do you really need to store them in Dictionary? You already have them in a collection right? you could use LINQ to filter on the collection itself.

```
var cityFiltered = from p in AnonymousClientList where p.city == 'London' select p;
```

etc.. and build your filtered collection.

**======UPDATE======**

Here is the updated query for filtering using city:

```
var filtered = (from c in clients where c.Value.city=="London" select c).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

If you see, the first part basically returns you a boolean value for your condition and not the dictionary object that you need. By using the ToDictionary method, you convert back to a Dictionary. So, now after execution of the LINQ, you will have all AnonymousClient with city set to London.

Comment: AnonymousClient is not a collection. It is the object type. I'm storing collection of objects of type AnonymousClient.

Comment: Most of the times I need to access a object from the collection using the unique ID. So it is better to have it in the dictionary as I can take the object straight away without using Linq to do that.

Comment: Yes, List is going to be slower compared to Dictionary in that particular case. and if you query more with id, you can go for that

Comment: Unfortunately, working with Dictionary is troublesome than you think.. I think you will have to use List itself.

Comment: Why is that so? Any reasons for that?